# Sharepoint template missing in Visual studio components

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I have got 4 components of visual studio 2010 express
1)MS Visual Basic 2010 express
2)MS Visual C#
3)MS Visual basic
4)MS Visual Web Devoloper. 
But none of them provide me Web part templates for sharepoint 2010. Which one would I need for this?
Do I need a proffessional? or even a Visual studio 12?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to have Visual Studio and SharePoint installed on the same machine in order to develop for SharePoint:

[Chris Hopkins' Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chhopkin/archive/2012/04/03/adding-the-sharepoint-2010-project-templates-to-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

I can tell you from personal experience this is true.  I've always had to install Visual Studio onto a SharePoint server when I wanted to write new solutions for SharePoint.

If you are simply trying to edit a page layout or master page, or some other static type of content in SharePoint, you can use many tools to do so.  I've successfully edited things with NotePad++ from my client PC.  As long as you have the permission for the library where those things are kept, you can make changes.

I originally thought you meant developing SharePoint SOLUTIONS, by which I mean additional back-end functionality, site features, and the like.

Comment: I have the designer permission and can edit sites and sitepages in browser. Do I need sharepoint to be installed to edit it in visual n?

Comment: That is exactly what I said in my answer.  I'll edit it to make it a little more clear

Comment: Thank you very much...that's a relief... :)

Comment: Hi Matt it seems that you don't need to have visual studio in the same machine as sharepoint. I don't know how? But I can edit sharepoint in visual studio just by providing link for that site if you have designer or permission above that.

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood what it was you were trying to do, then.  I've used Notepad++ to simply edit content in SharePoint 2013, so it's not a huge stretch to say you could do the same thing with Visual Studio.  This is a guide for creating Solutions for SharePoint:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231582.aspx

Comment: can you also help me with which site or page template should i create so that it is easy to edit in sharepoint designer? and also, when I edit a page in designer, a lot of options are there like,
Edit file in 1)Normal mode  2)Advanced mode &
Edit file with 1) HTML 2)Text 3)Notepad 4) Visual Web Devoloper.
I am using "Advanced mode" and I do my coding in html as I'm not an expert in ASP.

Comment: I think that's a little out of scope for your original question.  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com has a lot of SharePoint-specific answers, but you may just want to study up on working with SharePoint in general.  There is only so much you can do in SharePoint using only standard HTML.  SP has a ton of custom ASP.NET tags, as well as standard ones, and other custom functionality you wouldn't see in vanilla html pages.